# Best way to start becoming a wordpress developer

Tags: theme-development, customization

It's my mission this year to become a wordpress developer. I've been using wordpress for years as a frontside user but I now want to be able to develop wordpress sites from themes to functionality and cms. I already have a great understanding of CSS & HTML and some PHP(It's been a while), is there a great course anyone can recommend? Or where should I start? What languages does one need to be strong in? HTMl, CSS, JAVASCRIPT & PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [setting up a local install of WordPress](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/installing-wordpress-locally).  From there you can play around with different themes and plugins.  I would take a look at the code behind the default themes to see how they are built.

The best way to learn is by doing, so I would think of a site you can make and build it from scratch.  Maybe a portfolio site for you or whatever.  I don't think you really need to go through courses, just google what you need to know, there are plenty of free resources out there! Between this site and google it is pretty rare I don't find an answer immediately.

Here are a few resources to help.

- [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/)
- [Wordpress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/)
- [About Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
- [Creating a Theme](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch--net-706)
- [WP Beginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/start-here/)
- [List of Resources](https://winningwp.com/wordpress-resources/)

Comment: What languages does one need to be strong in? HTMl, CSS, JAVASCRIPT & PHP?

Comment: Yes, the only thing I would add to that list would be jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is by practice, so make a lot of Wordpress websites!

Otherwise, [lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/search?q=wordpress) has some excellent tutorials.